# Speficy parameters of a function that is an argument of another function in R

Tags: r

The title basically says it all.

I would like to pass a function to another argument, but I need to specify a parameter of the function that I use as input, e.g. here 0.5:

```
function1(function2(x, parameter = 0.5))
```

how do I do this in R ?

Comment: Define the function argument with the default you want. Say for instance that you want `colSums`, but with `na.rm=TRUE`. Just define `colSums2<-function(x) colSums(x,na.rm=TRUE)` and the use `colSums2`.

Comment: Yes that is how I always do it but this seems quite complicated and I wonder whether there is a more efficient solution

Comment: Is `function1` a function you defined? Usually, functions that take a function as argument provide an ellipsis (`...`) argument which are arguments to pass to the function argument. See for instance `?lapply`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some alternatives:

**1) define anonymous function**

```
# test data
fun2 <- function(x, y) x + y
fun1 <- function(fun, x) fun(x)

fun1(function(x) fun2(x, y = 2), 1)
## [1] 3
```

**2) partial in purrr package**

```
library(purrr)

fun1(partial(fun2, y = 2), 1)
## [1] 3
```

**3) Curry in functional package**

```
library(functional)

fun1(Curry(fun2, y = 2), 1)
## [1] 3
```

**4) %<% in curry package**

This package defines a `%<%` operator to do currying:

```
library(curry)
library(magrittr)

fun2 %<% 2 %>% fun1(1)
## [1] 3
```

**5) default package** This package lets one set arguments of a function to a default.

```
library(default)

default(fun2) <- list(y = 2)
fun1(fun2, 1)
## [1] 3

fun2 <- reset_default(fun2)
```

**6) dots** In certain cases the function to which another function is passed has a `...` argument which can supply arguments to the passed function.  For example, here we pass `a=1` to `obj` via the dots argument of `optimize`.

```
obj <- function(x, a) (x - a)^2
optimize(obj, c(0, 10), a = 1)
## $minimum
## [1] 1
##
## $objective
## [1] 4.437343e-31
```